# Cannot delete files, permissions are messed up (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, permissions

**What I did**
I just started using git, and I think I accidentally initialized a bare repository (instead of a normal one) in my www folder. So when I committed everything, I noticed it started removing everything, which I didn't expect at the time. That's where I made the mistake of killing git. Now there's two files that I can't delete/move/read/write/execute.
When I knew what git was actually doing, I then cloned the git repo in my www folder to my desktop, and it looks like I got most of it back, including those two files, which are normal, and I can write and read to them.

**What I'm trying to accomplish**
I realize that this may seem like an elaborate scheme to learn how to hack, but that's not the case, I own these files and my goal is to delete them, not break in. I'm unable to delete them however, as killing git seems to have messed up the permissions on the file. I really desperately need to know how to delete them, otherwise git and every backup system I use keep breaking on doing anything in this directory!

**Further info:**
I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate x64, and Git version 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0
Below a screenshot of the situation:
[image: screenshot permissions]
When I look at the permissions tab in the file properties, I get the message I have to have be an administrative user with permissions to view its security properties. I then clicked on continue, as I have administrative permissions (since it's my laptop). In the newly opened window I get the message I don't have permission to view its security properties. When I try setting its owner, as it suggests, I get the message "Unable to set new owner on [file]. Access denied".
I already tried using an elevated command prompt to try removing them, even forcefully.
I'm desperate, guys (and girls)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I wasn't able to delete the files, on Windows.. I finally did it using a linux (debian 6.whatever) live-cd, and using **`rm -rf logs/`**
So if anyone else should encounter the same thing, this is a relatively quick solution.